# Firefox addon: Can't use browser.tabs.create more than one time

Tags: javascript

I want my Firefox addon to open several browser tabs but Firefox only opens the first URL.

```
var creating = browser.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://mozilla.org',
    active: false
});

creating.then(onCreated, onError);

var creating = browser.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://example.com',
    active: false
});

creating.then(onCreated, onError);
```

example.com won't be opened. Is it something with the permissions? I even tried it with and without `active: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using `chrome.tabs.create({ url: adresse });`